# При просмотре профиля теперь не показывается время последнего посещения?

Tags: обсуждение, дизайн, профиль-участника

При просмотре профиля теперь не показывается время последнего посещения, или я просто не нашёл, куда смотреть?

Comment: Хм.. Модератору показывается, в приватном окне без входа - нет.

Comment: @MBo [Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285/440057)  Обсуждение вопроса, вернее сначала сделали, а сейчас обсуждают.

Comment: ну и в чем заключается их responsive? было несколько колонок, а теперь засунули все одну? Как всегда из нормального сделали уродливую хрень

Comment: @Alexandr_TT очень напоминает концепцию как сделать человека счастливым: сначала лишить его чего-то, а потом это вернуть. Хотя я всё же не особо уверен, что вернут, если уж в генеральной линии партии что-то щёлкнуло.

Comment: зато блок со знаками выглядит приятно и информативно

Comment: @αλεχολυτ скорее всего не вернут дату последнего посещения в профиле. Так как это очень удобно для администрации. Можно неделю, месяц на Мету, а также на другие сайты не заходить и никто не увидит, не упрекнет в бездеятельности.

Comment: Мда... Это не наши! (©)

Comment: А знаете как обидно, что они `got rid of the “Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them”`? Сами создали такую красивую метафору, которую, более того, так красиво перевели на русский. А теперь что? **НиЧеГо!** Буквально. Замены не будет. Белый фон!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Куда делась строка "last seen" в профиле пользователя?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11654/%d0%9a%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-last-seen-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f)

Comment: @Duncan MacLeod Вы немножко перепутали - это ваш вопрос является бубликатом

Comment: @MBo а я думаю ни то ни то не дубликаты друг друга. Один спрашивает о том, куда всё делось, а другой - о целесообразности и возможности настройки.

Comment: Очень плохое изменение, мне совсем не нравится.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Заморские коллеги [сделали скрипт](https://stackapps.com/questions/9074/legacyprofiles-bringing-back-the-old-profile-stats), который возвращает эту информацию в профиль.

На FF ставится через расширение TamperMonkey или GreaseMonkey.

Comment: Чего-то поменяли, демоны. Теперь скрипт версии 2.0 на буржуйском работает, на нашем - нет.

Comment: @MBo Зарепортил им баг, в 2.1 починили.

Comment: Спасибо. Не получится ли вечной войны брони и оружия? Скрипт подгонят, а реноваторы хреновы опять "по просьбам трудящихся" напортят...

Comment: @MBo Кто знает. Им стоит только убрать эту информацию из апи, и тогда никакие скрипты не спасут.