# Куда делась строка "last seen" в профиле пользователя?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, предложение, профиль-участника, настройки-профиля

Когда я нахожу вопрос, на который хочу дать ответ, то смотрю профиль пользователя, чтобы понимать, есть ли смысл ждать реакцию или нет. То же самое с комментариями, ответами и так далее.

Как мне это делать теперь?

В этом вопросе: [Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285) говорится, что:

> 7. Полностью удалена метрика "просмотры профилей". Это показатель тщеславия, и мы не думаем, что его стоит хранить.

В этом [ответе](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368382) предлагается решение: [LegacyProfiles](https://stackapps.com/q/9074), которое нормально работает пока. Используется просто JavaScript и Stack Exchange API.

Можно ли это реализовать в качестве дополнительной настройки в профиле пользователя, чтобы люди сами могли решать, является ли это *тщеславием* или нет?

Что на самом деле делает этот скрипт? Эта функция, показывать эту информацию или нет, может быть реализована в интерфейсе пользователя `frontend`, чтобы уменьшить нагрузку на сервер `backend`, если проблема в этом.

Каким должно быть приложение? Если приложение стало слишком сложным для обслуживания, тогда пришло время вернуться к его началу, т. е. к постановке задачи.

---

<sup>См. [Implement LegacyProfiles userscript as additional option in the user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368437)</sup>

Comment: Продублирую сюда комментарий из-под вопроса-"оригинала": `а я думаю ни то ни то не дубликаты друг друга. Один спрашивает о том, куда всё делось, а другой - о целесообразности и возможности настройки. – Алексей Шиманский 12 авг в 6:42`.